# VMWare Fusion - Disable Machine Name Display

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion

I'm running a Windows 7 virtual machine with VMWare Fusion on OSX. I keep my VM full screen in a Space (or whatever they're calling virtual desktops on OSX now). Every time I switch back to that Space, Fusion displays the name of the virtual machine in the top center of the screen.

I'm sure that's a wonderful feature for people who are running multiple VMs, but since I'm only running one, I don't need to be told which VM I'm looking at every time I switch to it.

Is there a setting somewhere to stop Fusion from showing me the VM name every time I switch to my fullscreen VM? I haven't been able to find one so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable display of the virtual machine name in full screen mode, edit the VMware Fusion preferences file:

```
Shut down any running virtual machines.
Quit VMware Fusion.
Open Finder.
On the Finder menu bar, click Go > Go to Folder.
Type this path and click Go:

~/Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/

Locate the preferences file.
Open the preferences file in a text editor.
Add this line to the file:

fusion.ui.fullscreen.nameBadge = "FALSE"

Save the file and exit the text editor.
```